# what happend ? when i try to import my project from eclipse to Android Studio,it just can't run correct?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

[image]

Now, i have problem that in the AndroidMenifest.xml, all of classes is wrong. And in Studio the APP can run , but is just flash past . before import to Android Studio, in the Eclipse , it' runs right . Anyone has an idea what's going on?

I really appreciate it .

Comment: u tried to migrate your eclipse android project over to android studio, and its giving errors in android studio? Have a look here: http://rexstjohn.com/exporting-android-project-eclipse-android-studio-0-4-0/

Comment: According to me this tutorial will help: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Android Studio, the best way to bring in an Eclipse/ADT project is to import it directly into Android Studio; we used to recommend you export it from Eclipse to Gradle first, but we haven't been updating ADT often enough to keep pace with Android Studio.

In any event, if you choose "Import Project" from the File menu or from the Welcome screen when you launch Android Studio, it should take you through a specialized wizard that will prompt you that it intends to copy the files into a new directory structure instead of importing them in-place, and it will offer to fix up some common things like converting dependencies into Maven-style includes and such.

It doesn't seem like you're getting this specialized flow. I think it may not be recognizing your imported project as an ADT project, and it's defaulting to the old built-into-IntelliJ behavior which doesn't know about Gradle. To get the specialized import working, the following must be true:

- The root directory of the project you import must have an **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
- Either:

  - The root directory must contain the **.project** and **.classpath** files from Eclipse
- or

  - The root directoy must contain **res** and **src** directories.

If your project is complex, perhaps you're not pointing it as the root directory it wants to see for the import to succeed.
Thank you.